# Fantasy book about two brothers in the afterlife

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read a great book once about two young brothers who die and go to the afterlife. The afterlife is a fantasy like world where they join the fight to free the world from an evil warlord. In the end, both boys die again, to join the final afterlife.

Do you know the name and author of the book?

Comment: Although my question focuses on the book and not the TV show. I was unaware that there even was a TV show. So I think that it is relevant to link the questions, but I do not necessarily consider this a duplicate question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Astrid Lindgren, "[The Brothers Lionheart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Lionheart)".